# Retrieve all rows from SQL Server and place into multiline textbox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve all rows from SQL Server and to place it in a multi line textbox. The query executes but it loads the last row maybe because its the last record. Should I have a 'foreach' statement?

```
private void LoadComments()
{
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_TestDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
   {
      using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("LoadNotes", con))
      {
         com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         con.Open();

         com.ExecuteNonQuery();

         SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

         while (dr.Read() == true)
         {
            TextBox1.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString() + " " + dr.GetValue(1).ToString() + dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do **not** call `.ExecuteNonQuery()` and then `.ExecuteReader()` one after the other! Use one of them - since you want to read the data, use only the `.ExecuteReader()` call - remove the other call

Comment: You can shorten your `while`-loop into `while(dr.Read())` as `.Read()` returns a bools

Answer (score 0):

Before While loop set `TextBox1.Text="";`
then try this code.

```
TextBox1.Text += dr.GetValue(0).ToString() + " " + dr.GetValue(1).ToString() + 
dr.GetValue(2).ToString()+Enviroment.NewLine;
```

In your Code your assingning each row to TextBox1 but you to concate the next row to TextBox1 so i put + before equal so it concate all rows.

Comment: It worked! but how to add new line? I added Environment.newline but it didnt worked.

Comment: I did it that way. but it didnt worked. I also tried  +"\r\n"

Comment: @user1954418 try `\r\n`

Comment: @user1954418 it working fine i dont know why not working in ur case?

Comment: @user1954418 try by setting Row Property of TextBox like  `TextBox1.Row=30`

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "";

while (dr.Read() == true)
         {
           str+= dr.GetValue(0).ToString() + " " + dr.GetValue(1).ToString() + dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
         }

 TextBox1.Text = str;
```